# VBA Excel worksheet selection change not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

The below code is not working... why?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     On Error Resume Next
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.EnableEvents = True

     If Target.address = "B9" Then
     Select Case Target.Value
        Case "English"
        Rows(6).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows(5).EntireRow.Hidden = False
     Case Else
        Rows(6).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows(5).EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End Select
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your title suggests you are interested in the `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` event but your code uses `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`.  Which event are you expecting to run your code?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
If Target.Address = "B9" Then
```

with:

```
If Target.Address = "$B$9" Then
```